# Is there an existing Quadtree implementation in libGDX?

Tags: libgdx, quadtree

I've seen a lot of sites that recommends to use [Quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) for splitting the array by levels and nodes for a better performance for example in `CollisionSystem` there's a lot of collisions needs to be handle. I need to ask this question because I'm planning to create my own `Quadtree` class, if there it didn't exist.

Comment: So are you asking if you can implement a QuadTree in Java (LibGDX)? Or if LibGDX has a QuadTree? Or if the LibGDX architecture supports (custom) QuadTrees? It is a little unclear right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GDX doesn't support it directly.

A version for LibGDX
https://github.com/alwex/QuadTree

Comment: It's not "for" libGDX, it uses `ArrayList` instead of `Array` and so it probably doesn't care about GC

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but here is an implementation that is specifically developed for use with libgdx: https://github.com/nahumrosillo/quadtree-libgdx